# Showing values over time in ggplot2 using bars instead of geometric points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data of the following type:

```
time <- c("2014-10-17 09:52:42 CEST", "2014-10-17 09:51:34 CEST", "2014-10-17 08:22:59     CEST", "2014-10-17 00:22:02 CEST", "2014-10-16 23:04:49 CEST", "2014-10-16 20:55:28 CEST")
time <- as.POSIXct(Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
value <- c(2, 2.5, 3, 6, NA, 3)
mydata <- data.frame(time, value)
```

It's easy to plot it as points:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=time, y=value)) + geom_point()
```

But I need to plot it as bars over time, and I cannot figure out how I can do it. I have looked through documentation on `ggplot2`, but nothing worked. It seems that bars are tailored to work with factor variables and not with time.

The closest thing that I have found is:

```
qplot(mydata$time)
```

But it plots *counts* instead of exact values. Once I try to add "y" variable to `qplot`, it starts to show geometric points instead of bars.

What else I can try?

Comment: Try `ggplot(mydata, aes(time, value))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")`

Comment: Thanks, it's better than points, it shows lines. Weirdly enough, not all the values are shown.

Comment: If you need `bars`, `ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(time), value))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+xlab("time")`

Comment: Converting it to a factor makes the graph incomparable with other graphs that I have, where continuous values are plotted over time. In this particular case, values are sparse and discrete, this is why I wanted to plot them as bars. Anyway, thank you, this is probably the best option so far.

Comment: Other options for time in the x-axis would be to convert to either `xts` or `zoo` object and use `plot`